# Remove vehicle information for transit routes in google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have made an application using the Transit layer of Google Maps API.My application page looks like this:
When I am creating the route I am getting two things which i want to erase from the map.
1) The markers A B which i removed successfully using suppressMarkers.

2)**The white info window in the image that provides me information about the kind of route used and the service used which can be seen in [this](https://www.google.com/maps?saddr=Vikhroli%20West,%20Mumbai,%20Maharashtra,%20India&daddr=Dadar%20West,%20Mumbai,%20Maharashtra,%20India&ie=UTF8&f=d&sort=def&dirflg=rT&hl=en) link.
like the window that say Mumbai CST-Kalyan which i want to remove**.

I am not able to find how to remove them.Please guide.

Comment: Did you try [suppressInfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions)?

Comment: @geocodezip : I tried using suppressInfoWindows but it still did not erase the infowindow .I did like this:
'var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(({suppressMarkers: true , suppressInfoWindows: true}));'

Comment: That isn't an infowindow it is transit information. I don't believe it can be removed unless you render the route yourself.

Comment: Is it possible to either make it invisible if not remove it completely.I am not able to find what it is called so that I can find out where is the origin.Please guide.

Comment: What about `I don't believe it can be removed unless you render the route yourself.` wasn't clear?  If you don't use the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) and you do render the route yourself, you would have to write code to make that appear. [Example of custom directions rendering](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render the directions your self like this example, those don't appear.

```
  function calcRoute() {
    polyline.setMap(null);
    var start = document.getElementById("search1").value;
    var end =  document.getElementById("search2").value;
    var request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: getSelectedTravelMode()
    };

    polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: [],
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeWeight: 3
    });

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var route = response.routes[0];
        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
        var detailsPanel = document.getElementById("direction_details");
        startLocation = new Object();
        endLocation = new Object();

        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
        detailsPanel.innerHTML = '<ul>';

        // For each route, display summary information.
        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
          var routeSegment = i + 1;
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
          summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
        }
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
          if (i == 0) { 
            startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
            startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
            createMarker(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
          }
          endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
          endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            detailsPanel.innerHTML += "<li>"+steps[j].instructions;
            var dist_dur = "";
            if (steps[j].distance && steps[j].distance.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;"+steps[j].distance.text;
            if (steps[j].duration && steps[j].duration.text) dist_dur += "&nbsp;"+steps[j].duration.text;
            if (dist_dur != "") {
              detailsPanel.innerHTML += "("+dist_dur+")<br /></li>";
            } else {
              detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</li>";

            }
            for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
              polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
              bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
            }
          }
        }

        detailsPanel.innerHTML += "</ul>"
        polyline.setMap(map);
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        createMarker(endLocation.latlng,"end",endLocation.address,"red");
        // == create the initial sidebar ==
        makeSidebar();

      }
    });
}
```